# Solana: How to setup github action (CI) for an Anchor Project

Tags: rust, github-actions, solana, anchor-solana, serum-project

I've my anchor project build with serum's anchor framework.
I want to set up github action, So that whenever a new pull request is raised or any commit is made on the main branch, I can be sure that no code has been broken and flag any such pull request.

Here is what I've tried. But it needs around 18 to 20 minutes to run and still unsuccessful.

```
name: Rust

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Install AVM
      run: cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor avm --force
    - name: Install Anchor
      run: avm install 0.24.2 && avm use 0.24.2
    - name: Build
      run: anchor build
    - name: Run tests
  run: anchor test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial approach was not efficient
cons:

- need many manual installations of solana, nvm, node and yarn
- hence too much time for a run
- complex
- reinventing wheel

When dug deep found out that found out that `serum` releases docker images for this purpose only. So I modified my action file to

```
name: Rust
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: projectserum/build:v0.24.2

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: List rustup toolchains
        run: rustup toolchain list
      - name: Set default toolchain
        run: rustup default stable
      - name: List rustup toolchains
        run: rustup toolchain list
      - name: Generate new keygen
        run: solana-keygen new
      - name: Set solana target cluster to local
        run: solana config set --url http:localhost:8899
      - name: Check solana config
        run: solana config get
      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Build
        run: anchor build
      - name: Run tests
        run: anchor test
```

It brought down the run time from 18 minutes to 3 minutes approximately.

References:

- https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/tree/master/docker
- https://github.com/yourarj/solana-twitter-enhanced/blob/main/.github/workflows/rust.yml